# 'especially' vs. 'particularly'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I was reading this sentence,

> During high school I was very talented student especially in math.

Automatically, I mentally corrected it as,

> During high school, I was **a** talented student, **particularly** in **mathematics**.

Then I paused, thinking why I replaced that *especially* with *particularly*. Was it because the original writing mentioned "M.Sc. program" and "PhD"? It seemed like I was trying to make the text sound a little more formal. But do I really have any ground here? I looked up some online dictionaries and found that not only they are synonyms, their definitions are also almost identical.

For example, according to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=particularly%20meaning),
*particularly* is defined as "to a higher degree than is usual or average," while *especially* is defined as "to a great extent; very much."

Or, in another definition, *particularly* is defined as "used to single out a subject to which a statement is especially applicable," while *especially* as "used to single out one person, thing, or situation over all others."

Does ***particularly*** really convey more formality than ***especially*** as I thought?

Comment: By the way, a common mistake among learners is using the word *\*especial* when they should be using the far more common *special*.  (It's not terribly relevant here, but I thought I'd mention it anyway :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that in this context, the two words are completely interchangeable with no change in meaning or register.

I can't actually think of a context where one would be preferred over the other, but I'm willing to be proven wrong on that.

Answer (score 3):

For a different situation I believe that the two words have a nuance to them.

Consider the following two statements:

1. > I like sushi, particularly salmon
2. > I like sushi, especially salmon

Although the person prefers salmon over other types in both examples, in the second statement the person expresses this stronger than in the first.

Comment: You are right! They express different dimensions while targeting the preference. Particularly is emphasising the salmon's specific qualities as the main difference of interest - the like is more accurate. Especially is emphasising the subject's higher level of feeling for the choice - the like is more emotional. Great examples.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply say that it sounds, to me, more sophisticated to say particularly. Though the two words, particularly and especially seem to be synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

I believe 'particularly' is used to denote ONE person, thing, or situation...and 'especially'...to denote ONE or MORE THAN ONE. I have no reference for this. I haven't heard 'particular' for denoting more than one.

Comment: Please consider adding some context and references.

Answer (score 0):

"Especially" means above all others. It is an adverb that is used to signify a person, thing or situation that is "more special" than all others.

"Particularly" can mean the same, but it can also be used in place of specifically. That I think is the nuance some of the above posters elude to.